# Is it possible to have both foreign key constraint and a trigger that keep the referential integrity?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, foreign-key-relationship

Is it possible to have both foreign key constraint and a trigger that keep the referential integrity?

I don't think that is possible and we have to remove the constraint and keep the referential integrity using trigger. To extend my description, suppose you have two tables one of them has a primary key and the other has a foreign key referring to the first table, primary key column. So now is it possible to add the following code

```
    create or replace TRIGGER TABLE1_TABLE2
    after update of TABLE1_PRIMARY_KEY on TABLE1
```

Of course it came to my mind to lose the constraint and continue with the trigger but is it the only way?

By the way this code is just for practice, I know it isn't a good idea to update the primary key of a table.

I found a useful article on one of Microsoft websites confirming my idea that the constraints should be removed. But of course the solution for Oracle may be different from any other database. The article is about [Implementing Referential Integrity and Cascading Actions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902684%28v=sql.80%29.aspx#sql_refintegrity_topic06) and the part that is related is "Implementing ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE with triggers" and after that comes "Before continuing, you need to drop the existing foreign keys".

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem doing that in Oracle. You could have both the constraint and the trigger at the same time.